# Changing equation to extend integer overflow

Tags: integer, overflow, long-integer, biginteger, integer-overflow

### Problem definition

I have a 2d scenario represented by a set of points (x,y), where x and y are 64bit integers. Both x and y values are in range of [0, R] (minimum possible x value is 0 and maximum value is R. Same rule applies for y).

At some point in my code i perform the following operation.

```
// Returns true if point P is inside circle defined by points A, B, C.
private bool InCircle(Long2 A, Long2 B, Long2 C, Long2 P)
{
    Long2 AP = P - A;
    Long2 BP = P - B;
    Long2 CP = P - C;
    return AP.SquareMagnitude * Long2.Det(BP, CP) + BP.SquareMagnitude * Long2.Det(CP, AP) + CP.SquareMagnitude * Long2.Det(AP, BP) > 0;
}

// Notes:
SquareMagnitude = x * x + y * y
Long2.Det(a, b) = a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x
```

I don't want this operation to fail, so the integers in it must not overflow. Maximum values occur when:

- A = (0, 0)
- B = (R, 0)
- C = (0, R)
- P = (R, R)

These points lead to:

- AP = (R, R)
- BP = (0, R)
- CP = (R, 0)

If these values run on the method, we get:

- AP.SquareMagnitude = R² + R²
- Long2.Det(BP, CP) = R²
- BP.SquareMagnitude = R²
- Long2.Det(CP, AP) = R²
- CP.SquareMagnitude = R²
- Long2.Det(AP, BP) = R²

And the result becomes:

- (2 * R² * R²) + (R² * R²) + (R² * R²) > 0

Which is the same as:

- 4 * (R^4) > 0

If we don't want a 64bit integer to overflow, then:

- 4 * (R^4) <= (2^63)

Thus, maximum R value is 2^15 = 32768. (It's actually 2^15.25, but we'll round it to 2^15).

---

### Question

Is there any way to increase maximum R value without getting overflow using 64bit integers? Something like breaking the equation down into smaller values and comparing them separately.

---

### My thoughts so far

I thought of changing the equation to:

```
return AP.SquareMagnitude * Long2.Det(BP, CP) > -BP.SquareMagnitude * Long2.Det(CP, AP) - CP.SquareMagnitude * Long2.Det(AP, BP);
```

Which would lead to:

- 2 * R² * R² > -(R² * R²) - (R² * R²)
- 2 * (R^4) <= 2^63
- R <= 2^15.5 (which still gets rounded to 2^15. Not good enough)

Besides, i don't know if it's safe to do this way. Is it?

Using integers is intended and output accuracy is a must.

I'm aware of this library:

[https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/robust.html](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Equake/robust.html)

But i want to use integers, not floats. The method being used here is robust within the integers overflow limitation. It is only desired to extend this overflow limitation.

Answer (score 0):

So i thought of running checked integer arithmetic and if it overflows, convert the 64bit integers to decimals.

```
// Returns true if point P is inside circle defined by points A, B, C.
private bool InCircle(Long2 A, Long2 B, Long2 C, Long2 P)
{
    Long2 AP = P - A;
    Long2 BP = P - B;
    Long2 CP = P - C;
    try 
    {
        long a = checked(AP.SquareMagnitude * Long2.Det(BP, CP));
        long b = checked(BP.SquareMagnitude * Long2.Det(CP, AP));
        long c = checked(CP.SquareMagnitude * Long2.Det(AP, BP));
        long lhs = checked(checked(a + b) + c);
        return lhs > 0;
    }
    catch (System.OverflowException)
    {
        decimal a1 = new decimal(AP.SquareMagnitude);
        decimal a2 = new decimal(Long2.Det(BP, CP));
        decimal b1 = new decimal(BP.SquareMagnitude);
        decimal b2 = new decimal(Long2.Det(CP, AP);
        decimal c1 = new decimal(CP.SquareMagnitude);
        decimal c2 = new decimal(Long2.Det(AP, BP);
        decimal lhs = a1 * a2 + b1 * b2 + c1 * c2;
        return lhs > 0;
    }
}

// Notes:
SquareMagnitude = x * x + y * y
Long2.Det(a, b) = a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x
```

Decimals can precisely represent integers < 2^96 if I'm not wrong. So to avoid precision loss and overflows:

- 4 * (R^4) <= 2^96
- R <= 2^23 (It's actually 2^23.5)

And to avoid overflows in the integers operations, (R² + R²) is the largest operation:

- R² + R² <= 2^63
- 2 * R² <= 2^63
- R <= 2^31

Using this method, maximum R value becomes 2^23, which is great.

Another thought: would the code run faster on average if the method would not try to perform checked integer arithmetic and instead converting the values to decimals and going decimals math right from the start?

Is this going to work? Did I make something wrong?